# React-redux connect() cannot wrap component defined as a class extending React.Component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I may be missing something, but I can't find any example where  `connect()` wraps a component defined as a class (extending `React.Component`), it always wraps components defined as a simple function.

A call like this:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeView)
```

where `HomeView extends React.Component`, I get a `Cannot call a class as a function` error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit (sorry for the ammount of code, I don't know what might be relevant):

**routes/Home/components/HomeView.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import './HomeView.scss'

class HomeView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Home</h4>
        <div id="g-signin2" data-onsuccess={this.props.signin} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
        gapi.signin2.render('g-signin2', {
            'scope': 'profile email',
            'width': 200,
            'height': 50,
            'longtitle': true,
            'theme': 'dark'
        });
  }
}

HomeView.propTypes = {
  signin : React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default HomeView
```

**routes/Home/modules/home.js**

```
export const HOME_SIGNIN = 'HOME_SIGNIN'

export function signin(newUser) {
    return {
        type: HOME_SIGNIN,
        payload: newUser
    }
}

export const actions = {
    signin
}

const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [HOME_SIGNIN] : (state, action) => {
      debugger;
      return Object.assign({}, state, {user: action.payload});
  }
}

const initialState = {
  user: null
}
export default function homeReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type];

  return handler ? handler(state, action) : state;
}
```

**routes/Home/containers/HomeContainer.js**

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {signin} from '../modules/home'

import HomeView from '../components/HomeView'

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  signin
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeView)
```

**routes/Home/index.js**

```
import HomeContainer from './containers/HomeContainer'

export default (store) => {
  component : HomeContainer(store)
}
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import CoreLayout from '../layouts/CoreLayout'
import HomeRoute from './Home'

export const createRoutes = (store) => ({
  path        : '/',
  component   : CoreLayout,
  indexRoute  : HomeRoute(store),
  childRoutes : []
})

export default createRoutes
```

Comment: Please share more code. You can wrap a component extending `Component` inside `connect()`. https://github.com/ming-soon/mern-starter/blob/master/app/routes/User/containers/ListContainer.js#L52

Comment: Can you show where you use this component (the parent) that you're seeing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you actually are correctly wrapping your component class in `connect()`.  Your problem is elsewhere, in routes/Home/index.js:

```
import HomeContainer from './containers/HomeContainer'

export default (store) => {
  component : HomeContainer(store)
}
```

the default export of `HomeContainer` is the [higher-order class returned by `connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#returns).  You're then trying to use `HomeContainer` as a function here, just like your console error says:

```
    HomeContainer(store)
```

.

Answer (score 6):

You *can* wrap a React component, whether it's a class or a functional component, with react-redux `connect`.

```
class MyDiv extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>hi</div>
  }
}

export default connect(({ stateStuff }) => ({ stateStuff }))(MyDiv);
```

Comment: Be careful with that:
It kills any performance optimizations because the Component will rerender after every state change. It’s better to have more granular connect() on several components in your view hierarchy that each only listen to a relevant slice of the state.

Read here:
https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect