# How to fix "dispatch is not a function" error in react native project

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux

In a react-native, redux, firebase project, I have a drawer component that subscribes to an `onSnapshot` listener when the component mounts, and on will unmount, it calls the snapshot reference. this component looks like this:

```
import { onAccountChange } from '../actions/Agenda';    
import {dispatch} from 'redux';

class DrawerContentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.unsubscribeAccount = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(this.props.authUser.uid).onSnapshot((doc) => {
        dispatch({type: types.LOAD_ACCOUNT, payload: doc.data()})

    });
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unsubscribeAccount();
    }

    < ...rest of component... >

EDIT:
    const mapStateToProps = ({ account, auth, inbox, agenda }) => {
    const { role, profileImg, legalName, username, rating, phoneNumber } = account;
    const { conversations } = inbox;
    const { authUser } = auth;
    const { events } = agenda;
    return {
        role,
        profileImg,
        legalName,
        username,
        rating,
        phoneNumber,
        authUser,
        conversations,
        events
    };
};

    const mapDispatchToProps = { logoutUser, onProfileChange, onAccountChange, getConversations, getAgenda };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DrawerContentComponent);
}
```

Edit: `onAccountChange()`:

```
export const onAccountChange = (uid) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
      firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).onSnapshot((doc) => {
        dispatch({ type: types.LOAD_ACCOUNT, payload: doc.data() });
      });
    };
};
```

The above functions as necessary, because I couldn't manage to unsubscribe from the action, which previously was placed in an external directory for actions.

Problem: I want to be able to implement this by somehow using the function thats already created in the actions file ( `getAgenda()`) without having to rewrite the code in the component, because im currently doing that just to have the ability to unsubscribe from the listener on unmount, only way I thought of to make it work.

ideally, id like to do something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.unsubscribeAgenda = this.props.getAgenda();
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.unsubscribeAgenda();
}
```

But the above results in:
`TypeError: 'dispatch is not a function'` if I take out the `dispatch` import, the error is `ReferenceError: Cant find variable: dispatch`, I obviously need to dispatch changes for a `onSnapshot` listener

What are some strategies to handle this?

Comment: What does your getAgenda action creator look like?

Comment: I dont have one ive never needed one. I have my actions in another directory, and initially was just calling them on mount through props. but that doesnt help me with having to call a reference to the onSnapshot listener to detach it and prevent app crash

Comment: Can you post what getAgenda's code is?

Comment: @ZacharyHaber check it out now, with `onAccountChange` instead for brevity, same concept, less code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import dispatch directly from redux.

You need to either use react-redux's connect() function to wrap your action creators with dispatch or get dispatch directly from it.

If you are using a functional component, you could use `useDispatch` to get access to it.

If you don't want to use one of the normal react-redux options, you can export dispatch from your store, and then import it from where you created your store.

```
export const dispatch = store.dispatch
```

If most of your logic for the firestore is in an redux thunk action (or similar with asynchronous capabilities), use connect to get the action wrapped in dispatch and run it as you have in your ideal at the end. Whatever you return from a thunk action is returned from the call as well, so you should be able to set it up to return the unsubscribe function.

```
 connect({},{onAccountChange})(DrawerContentComponent)
```

Then you can dispatch onAccountChange action creator using:

```
this.props.onAccountChange()
```

Edit:

Modify your onAccountChange function to this so that your thunk returns your unsubscibe function.

```
export const onAccountChange = (uid) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(uid)
      .onSnapshot((doc) => {
        dispatch({ type: types.LOAD_ACCOUNT, payload: doc.data() });
      });
  };
};
```

Then you just need to add onAccountChange to the mapDispatch to props and use this in your `componentDidMount` method:

```
this.unsubscribeAccount = this.props.onAccountChange();
```

Comment: ahh I see, so the issue was with not returning the actual firebase listener attachment

Answer (score 1):

For making components to be attached to store for both dispatch actions or mapping props, it is used with `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)`. in your case, there is no props passed to component so I'll just send `null` for `mapStateToProps`

(assuming you used `Provider` at some parent component [REDUX. I cant understand how to connect a component defined as a class extending React.Component in order to read the store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386044/redux-i-cant-understand-how-to-connect-a-component-defined-as-a-class-extending/61386343#61386343))

---

```
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 class DrawerContentComponent extends React.Component {
    ...rest code...
   componentDidMount() {
     this.unsubscribeAgenda = this.props.getAgenda();
    }
   componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeAgenda();
    }
   }
  export default connect(null, { getAgenda })(DrawerContentComponent)
```

Comment: what is `loadSuccess()` used for? because error coming from there... anyhow, you cant import at UI side something directly from `'redux'` and not `'react-redux'`, if you want to import `dispatch` against the normal flow of redux import it from your store